# How to use Data Annotations to validate a nullable int

Tags: c#

In an MVC 5 project, I have a model with a nullable int. For reasons that might not be productive to explain, it needs to be an nullable int and cannot be a string.

```
// Value can be null or an integer from 0 to 145        
[Range(0,145)]
public int? Criterion { get; set; }
```

The intended annotation is to provide user feedback when entering a value in a form.

```
Criterion: @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Criterion)
<span class="text-danger">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Criterion)</span>
```

While the user does get feedback when entering non-integer values, the Range attribute does not appear to work.

In order to enforce a nullable integer range, will I need to use regular expressions, or is there a simpler way to enforce the rule?

Comment: [Range(typeof(int), "0", "145", ErrorMessage = "Must beinteger value 0-145.")]

Comment: I think adding a regular expression allows numbers and space is a fairly simple solution.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav -- I tried that no validation occurred.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If I remember correctly, the `[Range]` data annotation should work as expected for nullable integers (i.e. it will only validate that a number falls within the range if one is present). You'll need to ensure that you are calling `ModelState.IsValid` within your `POST` action in order to trigger this server-side validation.

**Example**

The example below demonstrates using `null`, `-1`, `1` and `150` as input values along with their expected results :

[image]

You can [see an example demonstrating this here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/YdY4gV).

Comment: You're using a string. My model is a nullable int.

Comment: Oops, sorry for the typo. I've updated the example to use an `int?`, it should still work just as expected.

Comment: I see that it does work in your case. In the case of my BeginForm, I am not posting my ViewModel: I am submitting values used to _filter_ my ViewModel, so I don't think this will apply.

Comment: The same basic idea would apply. You don't necessarily need to post to the same ViewModel, you could creating a `FilteringModel` class and set the appropriate attributes on that and handle it that way if it makes more sense.

Comment: In case someone wonders:  
Microsoft specifies that the range attribute is not responsible for null values  
// Automatically pass if value is null or empty. RequiredAttribute should be used to assert a value is not empty.  
if (value == null) { return true; }  
https://web.archive.org/web/20230526072105/https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations/DataAnnotations/RangeAttribute.cs

Answer (score 11):

I know this is old but I had the same situation today, Just in case someone else is having the same problem you need to know that `Range` does not validate the null value, but you can use it with `Required` to make the validation possible, it would be:

```
[Required, Range(0, 145)]
public int? Criterion  { get; set; }
```

Here's an example based on Rion's fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/SBoqJA

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer, since as @nramirez said, `Range` validation attribute doesn't consider the `null` value. Anyway, doing this way there's still the problem that the value has to be filled since it's required. I had the same problem when creating a model for a web API that has a swagger interface. The swagger UI add the mandatory indicator `*` on the field.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom data annotation to do this pretty easily by inheriting `ValidationAttribute` and `IClientValidatable`.

```
public class ValidateNullableInt : ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        return IsValid(value != null ? value : null)
    }

    public override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext context)
    {
        bool isValid = false;
        if(typeof(value) == Nullable<int>)
        {
            int? temp = value as Nullable<int>;

            if(temp.HasVaue > minValue && temp.HasValue < maxValue)
            {
                return ValidationResult.Success;
            }

            return new ValidatonResult(errorMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where would I place those functions?

Comment: Create a folder with whatever name you want, I use `DataAnnotationExtensions`. Then, create a class with whatever you want it named `ValidateNullableInt` might work. And once you have it all done, just use it as a regular Data Annotation. Probably need to add a `using myProjectName.DataAnnotationExtensions` to the controller as well.