# Best way to control Error Message for decimal validation in ViewModel property validation?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a ViewModel property:

```
public decimal decProperty { get; set; }
```

I have found it difficult to customise the Error message for the above. However if I code the following, I can specify the error message.

```
[RegularExpression(@"\d+(\.\d{1,2})?", ErrorMessage = "Invalid decimal")]
public string strProperty { get; set; }
```

Ideally I just want to keep the type as "decimal?". How could I just specify "Invalid decimal" in this case?

Thanks.

Comment: Is it the same question http://stackoverflow.com/q/6587816/5311735?

Comment: Are you just wanting to change the actual error message that is displayed when you enter an invalid value?

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Yes I wanted to just change the default message which is displayed when .NET does it default type validation. Thanks.

Comment: Refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6214066/how-to-change-default-validation-error-message-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: @StephenMueke, Thanks but the problem with this is that it changes the messages globally and I want to just define custom messages for class scope or property scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `Range` attribute as a workaround. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38331814/how-to-use-data-annotations-to-validate-a-nullable-int), the range will only be tested if a value exists.

```
[Range(decimal.MinValue, decimal.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Invalid decimal")]
public decimal? decProperty { get; set; }
```

By the way, you can also define resources so your error messages become translatable.

```
[Range(decimal.MinValue, decimal.MaxValue, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources), 
    ErrorMessageResourceName = "Decimal_ValidationError")]
```

**EDIT**

As it turns out, `Range` only works for `int` and `double`.

Another way is to implement a custom `ClientDataTypeModelValidatorProvider` and `ModelValidator`. This gives you full control. They are registered in the Global.asax `Application_Start()`. This will work every time the ModelBinder tries to bind a decimal, no need to attribute every ViewModel. Unfortunately, I can't show you our implementation, because it is owned by the company. Use ILSpy to take a look at the code from MS.

http://jwwishart.blogspot.co.at/2011/03/custom-server-and-client-side-required.html

Comment: Thanks, this looks promising. Is it possible to set these annotations at class level?

Comment: The `Range` attribute only works on properties, fields or parameters. I fear the same is true for most other Attributes from `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`. Take a look at the `AttributeUsage` in the implementation of these attributes.

Comment: Range only supports "int" and "double". I am trying "double".

Comment: Oops I overlooked that. Note that `decimal` provides 8-29 significant digits, `double` only 15-16 digits, so I am not sure if this will work for you :(

Comment: No I am not sure... I think using regex is the best option so far. It is the most controllable as per my question example]

Comment: Take a look at `ClientDataTypeModelValidatorProvider `, this might be more suited to your requirement anyways.